# Bubble window opacity variation and position not working

Tags: c#, wpf, position, opacity

I want to make a bubble window that GRADUALLY appears and vanishes after having displayed a message. I want its position to be near the tray and in the constructor I use for that:

```
 var screenSize = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;
 this.Left = screenSize.Right - this.Width;
 this.Top = screenSize.Bottom - this.Height;
```

this has worked properly other times but now it doesn't.

Strangely enough also the opacity doesn't change. So to put it in a nutshell the window  appear all of a sudden with no gradual transition at the center of the screen instead than near the tray.

This is the code:

```
 public BubbleWindow(string strMessage, double milliseconds)
{
  InitializeComponent();

  btYes.Content = strMessage;

  var screenSize = System.Windows.SystemParameters.WorkArea;
  this.Left = screenSize.Right - this.Width;
  this.Top = screenSize.Bottom - this.Height;

  int interval = (int)(milliseconds / 25);
  for (double iii = 0; iii <= 1; iii += .1)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(interval);
    this.Opacity = iii;
    Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { }), DispatcherPriority.Render);
    this.UpdateLayout();
  }
  this.Opacity = 1;
}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is the value of milliseconds you're passing?

Comment: Basically 2000 but i varied it in order to understand why it is not working

Comment: Did you try using Storyboard? Its way more efficient than Thread.Sleep

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you are blocking the UI-Thread the whole time -> so no UI updates until the method finishes. I think you are better of with DoubleAnimation...

Comment: @AnupSharma and Philip W could you please elaborate this? I am not used to animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the position problem I had put the WindowPosition=CenterScreen in my xaml code. That overrode the .left and .top command.

For the sake of completeness this is the complete Fade IN - wait - Fade out cycle:

```
private Storyboard myStoryboard;

public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  DoubleAnimation fadeInAnimation = new DoubleAnimation() { From = 0.0, To = 1.0, Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) };
  fadeInAnimation.Completed += FadeInAnimation_Completed;
  myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
  myStoryboard.Children.Add(fadeInAnimation);
  Storyboard.SetTargetName(fadeInAnimation, MyRectangle.Name);
  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeInAnimation, new PropertyPath(Rectangle.OpacityProperty));
  // Use the Loaded event to start the Storyboard.
  MyRectangle.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(myRectangleLoaded);
}
private void myRectangleLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  myStoryboard.Begin(this);
}

private void FadeInAnimation_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DispatcherTimer timerFadeOut = new DispatcherTimer();
  timerFadeOut.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
  timerFadeOut.Tick += TimerFadeOut_Tick;
  timerFadeOut.Start();
}

private void TimerFadeOut_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DoubleAnimation fadeOutAnimation = new DoubleAnimation() { From = 1.0, To = 0.0, Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)) };
  myStoryboard = new Storyboard();
  myStoryboard.Children.Add(fadeOutAnimation);
  Storyboard.SetTargetName(fadeOutAnimation, MyRectangle.Name);
  Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(fadeOutAnimation, new PropertyPath(Rectangle.OpacityProperty));
  myStoryboard.Begin(this);
}
```

This works. That being said I am open to corrections.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your XAML

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Rectangle.Loaded">
  <BeginStoryboard>
    <Storyboard>
      <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="MyRectangle" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
        From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:5" />
    </Storyboard>
  </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

This is pure XAML way

Or you can use

```
<Storyboard x:Name="anim">
    <DoubleAnimation
        Storyboard.TargetName="MyRectangle" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
        From="1.0" To="0.0" Duration="0:0:5" />
</Storyboard>
```

and then start the animation from c#

you can take reference from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms752312(v=vs.100).aspx)